# javascript innerhtml issue

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to get the innerHTML value of a node. The value is `D&O`. When I try to get this value using innerHTML I'm getting D &amp[semicolon] O. Is there any option to get the exact value rather than encoded value using Javascript? Please help me.

Forum prevents me from entering semicolon after &amp

Comment: Must you get HTML (e.g. including tags like `A <b>and</b> B`), or just the text is fine?

Comment: I just need the text inside that node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
 return ("innerText" in node) ? node.innerText : node.textContent;
```

`innerHTML` will returns the *equivalent* HTML that would provide the text that you see.

Comment: Not supported by Firefox last time I checked. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.This is working in Chrome and Mozilla. i need to test this in IE also

Comment: great piece of code. One question, why do you use `("innerText" in node) ?...` instead of `(node.innerText) ?...` to check property existance? Because it might be emprty string that would evaluate to false?

Comment: For instance :) Also that it is the _correct_ way to check for the existence of properties as this does not call `[get]` on the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
element.firstChild.data;
```

Get the data in the text node contained in the element. If you want the text and not HTML that represents it, don't use innerHTML.

Comment: This only works as long as firstChild is a textNode, but if thats guaranteed then its a good fit.

Comment: True, but the question implied that was the case.